# Sitecore Lucene index directory exists, but no segments files

Tags: lucene, sitecore, lucene.net, sitecore6

Following the instructions in [this SDN document (PDF)](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sdn5/articles%202/administration/lucene%20search/lcd/lucene_search_engine-usletter.pdf), I added a custom Lucene index to a Sitecore 6.3 website (or so I thought):

- In the `<indexes>` section in `web.config`, I added my index definition:

```
<indexes>
  ...
  <index id="website" singleInstance="true" type="Sitecore.Data.Indexing.Index, Sitecore.Kernel">
    <param desc="name">$(id)</param>
    <fields hint="raw:AddField">
      <field target="created">__created</field>
      <field target="name">@name</field>
      <field target="body">body</field>
      <field target="template" storage="keyword">@tid</field>
      <field target="id" storage="unindexed">@id</field>
    </fields>
  </index>
</indexes>
```

- I added the index to the `master` database:

```
<database id="master" ...>
  ...
  <indexes hint="list:AddIndex">
    ...
    <index path="indexes/index[@id='website']" />
  </indexes>
</database>
```

- Since the `master` database already has `HistoryEngine` set up (by default), I did not make any additional configuration changes.

I can verify that the `system` index is getting populated correctly, as the search application in the Sitecore Desktop is able to find items, and the `~/Data/indexes/master/system` directory is chock full of Lucene index files.

However, although the `~/Data/indexes/master/website` directory was created automatically, there are no index files in it, and attempting to perform a search in my sublayout results in the following `System.IO.FileNotFoundException` (path abbreviated for simplicity):

> no segments* file found in Sitecore.Data.Indexing.FSDirectory@~/Data/indexes/master/website: files:

What additional changes do I need to make to get Sitecore to recognize the new index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing more some experimentation/research, I discovered that there was actually no additional configuration necessary.

Following the instructions in [this blog post](http://learningsitecore.blogspot.com/2010/10/no-segments-file-found-in.html), I simply rebuilt the search index for the master database, and everything started working!

I will have to keep an eye on it, though; I thought the search index would be updated automatically every 5 minutes (based on the value of the `Indexing.UpdateInterval` setting).